# Diff just tags of XML with XMLUnit (no text or attributes)

Tags: java, xml, diff, xmlunit

I'm trying to use XMLUnit to diff just the overall structure (no text/attributes) of two XML documents as follows with XMLUnit:

```
private static final String XML_HEADER = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";

        xhtml1 = XML_HEADER + "<b>Text</b>";
        xhtml2 = XML_HEADER + "<b>Different Text!</b>";

        Diff d = new Diff(xhtml1.trim(), xhtml2.trim());

        DetailedDiff dd = new DetailedDiff(d);
        dd.overrideElementQualifier(null);
        dd.overrideDifferenceListener(new IgnoreTextAndAttributeValuesDifferenceListener());
        List<Difference> l = dd.getAllDifferences();
        for (Difference difference : l) {
            System.out.println(d.toString());
        }
```

Despite the fact that I override the difference listener on the DetailedDiff, I still get the following result:

```
org.custommonkey.xmlunit.Diff
[not identical] Expected text value 'Text' but was 'Different Text!' - comparing <b ...>Text</b> at /b[1]/text()[1] to <b ...>Different Text!</b> at /b[1]/text()[1]
```

Does DifferenceListener not apply to getAllDifferences? And if so, is there another way to diff only tags?

Answer (score 1):

`IgnoreTextAndAttributeValuesDifferenceListener` downgrades the differences to "similar" not "identical", that's why they still show up in the list of Differences.

If you cannot live with "not identical" you'll need to use a `DifferenceListener` of your own - and will likely end up copying `IgnoreTextAndAttributeValuesDifferenceListener` changing just a single line.